# How to reconnect a client automatically on ratchetphp?

Tags: php, sockets, client, wss, reactphp

I'm using rachetphp to create a client for an api server.
But i have a problem, when my connection close, whatever the reason, i can't reconnect automatically.

here the lib i use : https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$connector = new Ratchet\Client\Connector($loop);

$connector('ws://127.0.0.1:9000', ['protocol1', 'subprotocol2'], ['Origin' => 'http://localhost'])
->then(function(Ratchet\Client\WebSocket $conn) {
    $conn->on('message', function(\Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface $msg) use ($conn) {
        echo "Received: {$msg}\n";
        $conn->close();
    });

    $conn->on('close', function($code = null, $reason = null) {
        echo "Connection closed ({$code} - {$reason})\n";
    });

    $conn->send('Hello World!');
}, function(\Exception $e) use ($loop) {
    echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    $loop->stop();
});

$loop->run();
```

I would like to try a reconnect every Seconds after a connection close.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is simple but it needs some refactoring. We must put the reconnect code in the handler that is executed when the connection is closed. In order to do that we pass the `$app` function inside self.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$connector = new Ratchet\Client\Connector($loop);

$app = function (Ratchet\Client\WebSocket $conn) use ($connector, $loop, &$app) {
    $conn->on('message', function (\Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface $msg) use ($conn) {
        echo "Received: {$msg}\n";
        $conn->close();
    });

    $conn->on('close', function ($code = null, $reason = null) use ($connector, $loop, $app) {
        echo "Connection closed ({$code} - {$reason})\n";

        //in 3 seconds the app will reconnect
        $loop->addTimer(3, function () use ($connector, $loop, $app) {
            connectToServer($connector, $loop, $app);
        });
    });

    $conn->send('Hello World!');
};

function connectToServer($connector, $loop, $app)
{
    $connector('ws://127.0.0.1:9000', ['protocol1', 'subprotocol2'], ['Origin' => 'http://localhost'])
        ->then($app, function (\Exception $e) use ($loop) {
            echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
            $loop->stop();
        });
}

connectToServer($connector, $loop, $app);

$loop->run();
```

The idea is that when the connection receives the `close` event we do a reconnect using the `connectToServer` function:

```
$conn->on('close', function ($code = null, $reason = null) use ($connector, $loop, $app) {
    echo "Connection closed ({$code} - {$reason})\n";

    //in 3 seconds the app will reconnect
    $loop->addTimer(3, function () use ($connector, $loop, $app) {
        connectToServer($connector, $loop, $app);
    });
});
```

Comment: Very nice ! with this i can reconnect after an 'error' too or a 'close' event.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pnctl (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) installed, you can just change the 'close' handler to this:

```
$conn->on('close', function($code = null, $reason = null) {
    echo "Connection closed ({$code} - {$reason})\n";

    // restart myself
    global $argv;
    pcntl_exec($_SERVER['_'], $argv);
    exit();

});
```

For me this was simpler because I didn't already have the $loop and $connector extracted, I am just using

```
\Ratchet\Client\connect($ws_url, [], $headers)
    ->then(function ($conn) {
        echo "connected\n";
        ...
```

To handle it in multiple places, I created a little helper function that I call on those events (based on the case, I add a delay).

```
function restartMyself() {
  global $argv;
  pcntl_exec($_SERVER['_'], $argv);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: I would love if you'd elaborate on what you were talking about here, as I've been unable to get the accepted answer to work and was hoping that yours would. But https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php says "Process Control should not be enabled within a web server environment and unexpected results may happen if any Process Control functions are used within a web server environment.", which scares me.

Comment: That's why I said, "If you have it installed".  If you call it from a web-server (apache mod_php or php-fpm) it could cause bad things to happen. If you control the environment and know it's only being used from the CLI, then it works.

Comment: I'm doubtful if this is a good idea.
To elaborate what he is doing:
He is not reconnecting, he is restarting the entire php process from low level.
This means the whole php bootup is restarting, it likely has a bad performance impact compared to a real connection restart.

It also means every variable is reset, you lose your entire program-flow that way. 

Of course only for CLI scripts, apache would not like that